# size of object is different than size of class having no pointer

Tags: c++, class

Can anyone just let me know one case where size of object is different than the size of the class.

Suppose I have a

```
class A {

// I don't know what content can cause this.

};

sizeof(A)!=sizeof(*(new A()))
```

Note : Class should not contain any pointers.

Comment: This makes no sense. By definition, the size of a type is the size of an object of that type.

Comment: ...this is a pretty poorly worded question. Do you mean is there any case where `A& a = foo(); size_of(a) != size_of(A)`?

Comment: Yes Mike, I agree with you. Was asked in one of the seminars and confused me too. I can only figure out if a class contains a pointer of another class object.

Comment: @MikeSeymour perhaps an object of a derived class with no member variables but a virtual method? the class would technically be empty, as far as variables are concerned, but would have vtable overhead? or am i just talking out of my ass? can i say ass here?

Comment: @rock The thing is the size of a pointer is constant, so the size of the class doesn't change if it has pointers or not. The amount of memory a class is responsible for is not the size of the class.

Comment: edited @MadScienceDreams for more clarity

Comment: tested out with virtual classes, still same. i seriously don't see how they could be different.

Comment: Guys, there is a (contrived) case where `sizeof(A)!=sizeof(*(new A()))`.  I've made an answer.  It's probably useless, but maybe it's a fun trick question to play on your colleagues!

Answer (score 2):

These two are a different size.  I didn't try to 'interpret' your question about sizes of objects and classes,  I simply tried to contrive a situation where `sizeof(A)!=sizeof(*(new A()))`.

(Also, the question clearly did say `class A {...};`.  In that case, the sizes are identical.  But I allowed myself to define A differently in order to contrive an answer.  So, I guess I didn't answer the question as asked, I answered the question I wanted to hear!)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


typedef int A[10];

int main() {
        cout << sizeof(A) << endl;          // 40 (on 32-bit machines)
        cout << sizeof(*(new A())) << endl; // 4 (on 32-bit machines)
}
```

*Update,* I think I can explain this.  When `T` is an array type `T = X[n]`, then pointer decay kicks in and `new T` becomes `new (X*)`.  This would explain the numbers I'm getting.  Anybody get relevant standard quotes?

Therefore `sizeof(A)` is `10*sizeof(int)`, but `sizeof(*(new A()))` becomes `sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: Your update is the correct explication.  If `new []` is involved, `sizeof(*new X[i])` corresponds to `sizeof(X)`, regardless of `i`.  And when you achieve this by means of `typedef`, you can get the results you post.

Comment: And good catch.  He did ask about the contents of a class (where it isn't possible), but you've effectively found a case where his inequality is valid.  (Yet another reason to not use `new[]`?)

Comment: This 'typedef int A[10]' is a complete different animal

Comment: I must admit, I'm curious about the role of `new[]`.  Are we sure it's involved?  More precisely, should `delete[]` be used?  I must admit, I never really took the time to understand `delete[]` fully.

Comment: To answer my own question, `delete []` should be used on pointers that came from `new A`, where A is an array type.  I overloaded the `new` operator to confirm that `new[]` is being called, even though we can't see any `[` or `]` explicitly in `new A`.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any.  `sizeof` is a constant expression: `sizeof`
a type gives the size of the type, and `sizeof` an expression
gives the size of the static type of that expression.  There are
no exceptions; that is the definition of the operator.

EDIT:

Following up, taking Aaron McDaid's answer into account:
this is only true for non-array `new`.  There's nothing you
can put in a class which would invalidate it, but if the "type"
is defined by a typedef, to be a C style array, `new[]` is
involved, and there can be differences.